# Expose interface methods names

Tags: c#, spring, reflection, system.reflection

I'm working in a method that invoke a class method using reflection and getting my service object class from spring. Something like this:

```
private void InvokeMethod(string serviceName, string methodName, params object[] arguments)
    {
        object service = SpringContextManager.Instance.GetObject(serviceName);
        Type classType = service.GetType();
        MethodInfo method = classType.GetMethod(methodName);
        method.Invoke(service, arguments);
    }


//...

InvokeMethod(SpringObjectsConstants.LogDocumentService, "SetDocumentStatus", 9127, LogDocumentPendingStatusEnum.Finalized)
```

I need to inform the method name as a string so the method can call it, but I dont want to work with strings because if the method name changes, I can´t track the usages of it.
There is any way to work with the interfaces methods that look like an enum or something? Anything that could cause compilation errors or I can update renaming the method name in visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

There is a refactoring-safe way: You can use an expression and parse that. The idea is the same as in [this article](http://digitaltapestry.wordpress.com/2009/03/20/reflecting-on-code/).
Unfortunately, it gets a bit messy when you use methods instead of properties, because you need to pass the arguments to the method.

Having said that, there is a much more elegant solution. It simply uses a delegate

However, I don't really see the need for reflection here at all. You can simply pass a delegate:

```
InvokeMethod<ServiceImpl>(
    SpringObjectsConstants.LogDocumentService,
    x => x.SetDocumentStatus(9127, LogDocumentPendingStatusEnum.Finalized));
```

This would have another advantage: If you changed the type of a parameter or added or removed a parameter from the method, you also would get a compilation error.

`InvokeMethod` would look like this:

```
private void InvokeMethod<TService>(
    string serviceName, Action<TService> method)
{
    TService service = (TService)SpringContextManager.Instance
                                                     .GetObject(serviceName);
    method(serviceName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Improving my description, for some reasons I need to build a list of "commands" to invoke. Them, when my process ends, I need to invoke all the commands in the list in the same DB transaction scope so I can garantee a rollback of all of them in case of error. This is why I need to store the commands. In this case, the delegate would be the best way? My service methods have different signatures.

Comment: @Rafael: Not sure about your comment, but you can easily store a delegate. The different signatures are not a problem. Check the `method` parameter in my implementation of `InvokeMethod`. As you can see, it only requires the type you want to execute the method on. All the rest is contained within the delegate.

Comment: Thanks again. I did some tests but in the way my code and classes are structured, this way (delegate and action) won't work.